# Как ограничить доступ к процессу пользователя?

Tags: windows, процесс, реестр, права, explorer

необходимо ограничить доступ к процессу explorer.exe у пользователя компьютера. Чтобы под админом explorer стоял в автозапуске, а у сторонних пользователей не было прав на него.

ALSO:

1. Засунуть батник в авторан плз не предлагать, ибо сначала прогружается раб стол, а только потом авторан запускает свои программы, соответственно есть доля времени, когда отображается панель задач для юзеров
2. Автоскрытие соответственно тоже не предлагать

Нужно именно, чтобы у гостевого пользователя не было прав на запуск explorer.exe, таким образом сразу отключаются Win + ... хоткии, и explorer не будет подгружаться, а потом исчезать.

Comment: Это абсолютно бесполезная и, весьма возможно, вредная идея. Нет никаких причин делать что-то подобное.

Comment: @Qwertiy , возможных кейсов множество, например: салон связи , чтобы менеджеры имели доступ только к одной программе компании, которая стоит в авторане, интернет салоны, комп салоны и др

Comment: Для выполнения любого действия, которое можно сделать через проводник, достаточно иметь запущенный блокнот. А точнее, вообще любую программу, имеющую стандартный диалог открытия или сохранения файла. Так что запрет проводника на роль защиты от чего-то ну никак не годится - если ты предполагаешь, что у пользователя есть возможность запустить проводник, то он воспользуется ей для запуска блокнота и сделает всё то же самое. А с другой стороны, проводник - важная часть системы и я бы посомневался о стабильности работы системы при запрещённом проводнике.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашел методом тыка простой и несложный способ. Предложенными выше способами не получилось реализовать. Сторонним по пользоваться не хотелось А в shell засунуть другое ПО - не есть хорошо.

И так, идем в

1. `C:\Windows\ → находим файл explorer.exe → ПКМ → Свойства`
2. `Безопасность → Дополнительно → Меняем владельца с TrustedInstaller на <Admin>`
3. Закрываем окна нажатиями на `Применить` и `Ок`
4. `Снова ПКМ → Свойства → Изменить → Выбираем пользователя, у которого надо убрать Explorer → Снимаем галочки с "Чтение и выполнение", "Чтение"`

   5. Скачиваем программу [Autoruns](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/autoruns) с Microsoft → Запуск от админа → В меню Users выбираем таргет юзера и во вкладке Logon снимаем галку с Explorer.exe
   6. Все закрываем, перезагружаемся, проверяем

[image: Дополнительно → Меняем TrustInstaller на вашего админа]
[image: Убираем галочки и сохраняем]

Answer (score 1):

Можно и правами NTFS ограничить доступ к Проводнику. Но есть стандартные решения - политики по ограничению использования проводника + замена оболочки Windows.
Инструкция относительно последнего действа.
Нужно заменить оболочку пользователя, да хоть на командную строку.

1. Запустить Редактор реестра.
2. Найти следующую ветвь пользователя, которому нужно убрать Проводник как оболочку.

   HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon
3. Создать строковый параметр: **Shell**
4. Задать значение **cmd.exe**
   Можно использовать другие приложения (да хоть 7-zip).
5. Ограничить политиками Проводник или запретить запуск explorer.exe с помощью редактора груповых политик - оснастка **gpedit.msc** в разделе **Конфигурация пользователя** - **Административные шаблоны** - **Система. параметр**. Параметр **Не запускать указанные приложения Windows**. 
   Впрочем, можно это сделать и шаблонами безопасности, либо списками разрешенных к запуску приложений и т.д.

Comment: Существуют как платное, так и бесплатное ПО для управления политиками по ограничению стандартного интерфейса пользователя. Folder Guard, Security Administrator, Родительский контроль и т.д.

Comment: `progman` - стандартная пустая оболочка.